Angular Material Dialog Causes Browser Crash or Refresh on iPhone When Zooming
I am developing a website using Angular 14 and Angular Material. I've encountered a browser-specific issue on iPhones (both Chrome and Safari) where the browser either crashes or navigates away from the current page when a Material dialog is displayed and the user attempts to zoom in. This issue does not occur on Android devices or desktop browsers.
The problem seems to arise when there is vertical scrolling within the dialog, and the user plays with the zoom, but I am not certain if these are the only conditions that trigger the issue.
Here is a simplified version of the components involved:
headline.component.html:

<div (click)="openDialog()" class="bg-danger d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 250px">

headline.component.ts:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { TestDialogComponent } from './test-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-headline',
  templateUrl: './headline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./headline.component.scss']
})
export class HeadlineComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(TestDialogComponent, {height: '350px'})
  }
}

test-dialog.component.html:
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: 350px">
  <p style="font-size: 50px">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </p>
  <p style="font-size: 50px">bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye bye</p>
  <p style="font-size: 50px">hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi </p>
</div>

You can see the issue demonstrated in this video: Video Link.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or does anyone have any insights on what might be causing these crashes? How can I prevent this behavior on iOS devices?
I set up an Angular Material dialog that opens when a user clicks on a specified div in my Angular 14 application. This dialog contains content that is scrollable and includes large text elements. I tested the behavior of this dialog on various devices and browsers.
